# Possible to require a file be saved before closing?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to require a file be saved before closing a file in Excel VBA? I've Googled this and was able to find that you can disable saving, but couldn't find the reverse -

```
Application.ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `thisworkbook` module

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel as Boolean) 
 If Me.Saved = False Then Me.Save 
End Sub
```

[KB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194765.aspx)